# Dreamhost: Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, dreamhost

I have been working on this problem in last two days using [http://jackassofalltrades.org/2012/02/updating-to-a-newer-rails-on-dreamhost][1]/ instruction.  I have looked at other ruby on rails and dreamhost issues and instructions, but they seemed out of date. e.g 2010 etc.  Moreover, I do aware of heroku which is very easy to deploy but expensive to keep running for my small project. So here are my problems.

1. Ruby (Rack)application could not be started - a mixture of two Ruby versions: Ruby 1.8  and 1.9 - when visiting to my website via browser.
2. I am unsure whether the gemset rails_michaelcollins_com remains true when i exit the terminal because every time I log in, the arrow to the particular gemset have been missing from "rvm gemset list".
3. Rails console error message stating "Could not find a JavaScript runtime" despite that I have Execjs 1.3.1 according to "bundle show" in rails.michaelcollins.com folder.

Thank you kindly in advance

---

```
Error mesage: Ruby (Rack) application could not be started
Application root: /home/miccol2/rails.michaelcollins.com
```

---

```
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  in `exit'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `require'
/home/miccol2/rails.michaelcollins.com/config/boot.rb   6   
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
/home/miccol2/rails.michaelcollins.com/config/application.rb    1   
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
/home/miccol2/rails.michaelcollins.com/config/environment.rb    2   
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require' config.ru  3   
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb 46 in `instance_eval'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb 46 in `initialize'
config.ru 1 in `new'
config.ru
```

---

```
[oslo]$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
[oslo]$ which ruby
/home/miccol2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
[oslo]$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
[oslo]$ which rails
/home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
[oslo]$ rvm -v

rvm 1.13.4 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

[oslo]$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
   rails_michaelcollins_com

[oslo]$ rvm gemset use rails_michaelcollins_com
Using ruby-1.9.3-p194 with gemset rails_michaelcollins_com
[oslo]$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p194 (found in /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194)
   global
=> rails_michaelcollins_com

[oslo]$
```

---

```
[oslo]$ rails console
    /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/execjs-1.3.1/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:50:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/execjs-1.3.1/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/execjs-1.3.1/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee_script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0/lib/coffee-script.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/coffee-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/rails.michaelcollins.com/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `require'
            from /home/miccol2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails_michaelcollins_com/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
            from script/rails:6:in `require'
            from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    [oslo]$
```

---

```
[oslo]$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.3)
  * actionpack (3.2.3)
  * activemodel (3.2.3)
  * activerecord (3.2.3)
  * activeresource (3.2.3)
  * activesupport (3.2.3)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.3)
  * coffee-rails (3.2.2)
  * coffee-script (2.2.0)
  * coffee-script-source (1.3.1)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * execjs (1.3.1)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.3)
  * jquery-rails (2.0.2)
  * json (1.7.1)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.18)
  * multi_json (1.3.4)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.3)
  * railties (3.2.3)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * sass (3.1.17)
  * sass-rails (3.2.5)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * thor (0.14.6)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
  * uglifier (1.2.4)
[oslo]$
```

Comment: I can't give you a helpful answer, but I found dreamhost to be pretty messed up on the backend,  and I ended up spinning up a rackspace server and being much happier for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've bundled `execjs` but it can't find a Javascript runtime, like, say, `node.js`.

If you truly need `execjs`, then install `node.js`.

Also, be sure that your PATH environment variable includes the path to your Javascript runtime installation before starting up Rails.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that node.js enables to get my rails app to work.  FYI: http://dandean.com/nodejs-on-dreamhost-shared-server/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `execjs` can't find it a runtime JS server.

See this for morre information:

```
https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
```

Do you need that gem? If so, you'll need to install a runtime JS server. One widely used one is https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer .

To install that runtime JS server, add this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem "therubyracer", :require => 'v8'
```